# How to paste a directory into a git repository

Tags: git, version-control, assembla

So I have a git repo and I'm trying to paste a directory into it. I clone the repo, checkout a new branch and paste the directory in one of the sub directories. So the file path is like this

```
Repo/ios/parentDir/directoryPastedIn
```

When I'm in the parentDir and I do a git branch, I see that I'm on the branch that I checked out. When I'm in `directoryPastedIn`, I do a `git branch` and see that I'm on `master`, instead of that branch.

When I do a git status while I'm in the parent Dir I get this(after I've done a git add -A) -

```
# On branch someBranch
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   directoryPastedIn
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   directoryPastedIn (modified content)
#
```

However, when I go into the directoryPastedIn and go into some of it's sub directories and do a `git status`, I see that there are untracked files. When I push this to the remote, I see that a binary file has been pushed, rather than a directory.

So how do I paste in a directory into my local git repo and push it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have pasted in a directory that itself includes a git repository.

Check to see if the pasted directory has a `.git` subfolder. If so, and if you don't want that repository, remove that`.git` folder.